# 3D Image Rotation Simple ITK Python

Tags: python, image, image-rotation, simpleitk

I'm trying to rotate a 3D-Image with Simple ITK.
Here is my Code:
*imagetoresize* is the original image. The size of the image is (512,512,149)

```
targetimage = imagetoresize
origin = imagetoresize.GetOrigin()
targetimage = imagetoresize
imagetoresize.SetOrigin((0,0,0))
transform = sitk.VersorTransform((0,0,1), np.pi)
transform.SetCenter((256,256,74))
outimage=sitk.Resample(imagetoresize,targetimage.GetSize(),transform,sitk.sitkLinear,[0,0,0], imagetoresize.GetSpacing(), imagetoresize.GetDirection())
outimage.SetOrigin(origin)
```

The code rotates the image but the center is shifted.
[Orginal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75W7G.jpg)
[Image after rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akTUo.jpg)

Can someone explain to me why the center is shifted?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You appear to be assuming the physical points are the same as the indices of the image. Can you please share the rest of the meta-data of your image? The spacing, origin, and direction matrix.

Comment: Orginal:
     Dimension: 3
     Dimensions: 512 512 149 
        Matrix: 
          0.832031 0 0 
          0 0.832031 0 
          0 0 1.5 
        Offset: [-200.584, -382.084, -1431.5]
        Center: [0, 0, 0]
        Translation: [-200.584, -382.084, -1431.5]
        Inverse: 
          1.20188 0 0 
          0 1.20188 0 
          0 0 0.666667 
        Scale : 1 1 1 
         Origin: [-200.584, -382.084, -1431.5]
         Spacing: [0.832031, 0.832031, 1.5]
         EvenlySpaced: 1
         DirectionVector: [0, 0, 1]
         Slices: 149

Comment: Rotate:     
Dimension: 3
     Dimensions: 512 512 149 
        Matrix: 
          0.832031 0 0 
          0 0.832031 0 
          0 0 1.5 
        Offset: [-200.584, -382.084, -1431.5]
        Center: [0, 0, 0]
        Translation: [-200.584, -382.084, -1431.5]
        Inverse: 
          1.20188 0 0 
          0 1.20188 0 
          0 0 0.666667 
        Scale : 1 1 1 
         Origin: [-200.584, -382.084, -1431.5]
         Spacing: [0.832031, 0.832031, 1.5]
         EvenlySpaced: 1
         DirectionVector: [0, 0, 1]
         Slices: 149

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the center of rotation in pixels and not in physical space.

SimpleITK ( and ITK ) perform transformation and resampling in physical space and not index space. It should be unnecessary to set the origin of you image to **0**. I believe the you should use imagetoresize.TransformContinuousIndexToPhysicalPoint(center_index) to obtain the center in physical space.

Comment: Thanks your advice! it was really helpful.
But i must set the origin to 0 otherwise i get a black image.